# Statistics based scheme for assigning weight to exam questions

Tags: example, variance-stabilizing

I have a memory of taking some undergraduate statistics course, and the lecturer doing an example where he had a scheme for assigning weights to the problems of an exam based on the students performance. I think the larger related topic was something like variance stabilizing transformations, and the scheme ended up not really doing anything a human would not do.

Can any of you recall such a scheme? I'm grading a series of exams now, and it looks like it is designed in such a way that the score on some questions will be very correlated, and I would like some rationale in assigning weights to each question